# wordpress query with lastname from title

Tags: wordpress

I have a list with hundreds of people and their full name (first last) is in the title. Is there a method to query these posts in alphabetic order but using the last name (second word) from the title?

I found this http://ms-studio.net/tutorials/sorting-titles-by-last-name-in-wordpress/ but i cant understand how it would work in wp query

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    function posts_orderby_lastname ($orderby_statement) {
        $orderby_statement = "RIGHT(post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(post_title)) - 1) ASC";
        return $orderby_statement;
    }       

    add_filter( 'posts_orderby' , 'posts_orderby_lastname' );

    ?>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=person&posts_per_page=100' );

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

        <?php endwhile; 
        remove_filter( 'posts_orderby' , 'posts_orderby_lastname' );    
        wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

this worked